# Reloading External file field with server up

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solrconfig

I am trying to implement an external file field in order to change ranking values in Solr.

I've defined a field and field type in the schema and, in the "solrconfig.xml", bellow the `<query>` tags, created the external file and added the reload listeners as described in the [ref guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-external-files-and-processes.html#WorkingwithExternalFilesandProcesses-ReloadinganExternalFile):

After server start up, I'm able to sort the documents based on that previous created field, however, when i change the values while the server is up and when I make a new search query, I'm not able to see the updated rank list (neither the updated rank scores).

I also tried adding a reload request handler as suggested in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037694/using-an-external-file-to-boost-results-changes-in-the-external-file-not-reflec) and tried a force commit (http://HOST:PORT/solr/update?commit=true), but it says:

```
DirectUpdateHandler2 No uncommitted changes. Skipping IW.commit.
DirectUpdateHandler2 end_commit_flush
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get any messages when calling the reload request handler? Have you tried issuing [a core reload](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD)? And is there any reason why the ranking value couldn't be part of the Solr document itself? (since we now have in-place updatable fields with docValues)

Comment: @MatsLindh when I call the reload request it appears those two lines that i mention above ('No uncommited changes,...').
A core reload solves the problem, but it is  expensive in terms of performance and time.
Thanks for pointing me the in-place updatable fields, I wasn't aware of that feature and it fits really well in my case and solves this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Using ExternalFileFields for scoring is really not that useful any more, since Solr and Lucene [now supports In-place updates for values that uses docValues](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-In-PlaceUpdates).

You can then use those fields directly from your document for scoring, and you can update them without having to update the whole document. That way you don't have to reload anything externally, and your caches can be managed automagically by Solr.

There are three conditions a field has to pass for in-place updates (that being said, atomic updates can also be used, but that requires all your fields to be set as stored):

> An atomic update operation is performed using this approach only when
>   the fields to be updated meet these three conditions:
>
> - are non-indexed (indexed="false"), non-stored (stored="false"), single
>     valued (multiValued="false") numeric docValues (docValues="true")
>     fields;
> - the _version_ field is also a non-indexed, non-stored single valued
>     docValues field; and,
> - copy targets of updated fields, if any, are also non-indexed,
>     non-stored single valued numeric docValues fields.

Comment: let's assume a case where a score field for 90% of the documents are required to be changed every X hours, in that case ExternalFileField would still be useful to reduce the write traffic on solr, right?

Comment: Sure, test it and evaluate how it behaves under your requirements.

Comment: The initial results came in favor of Eff, i will be doing a proper benchmarking soon enough. But as you rightly pointed that it is not cloud-aware and many of the current users might be using solr-cloud only. for now i have added a work-around solution here: https://medium.com/@parts.of.programming/practical-recipes-apache-solrcloud-external-file-field-a2d4091e36ce covering about a possible integration workflow and it may come in handy for someone visiting the same topic later.